# What happens if you have one imap client and one pop client?

Tags: email, imap, pop3

I have a mailbox on my server which accepts POP and IMAP connections. If I connect one remote client via POP and another remote client via IMAP, what will happen?

Will the emails remain on the server or will they be removed to the POP client?

Comment: It depends. Try it and you'll find out.

Answer (score 3):

When the POP client connects, and assuming it is not configured to leave a copy of the email on the server, then it will download and remove them. The IMAP client will see whatever mail is present on the server at the time it connects.